# R : Fill NaN with value or update value of one column based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe (sample) as given below
(8K rows and 1.6K sellers)

```
# creat dataframe
df <- data.frame(name =c('Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom',Tom','Tom','jack','jack','jack','jack','jack','Malik'),
                week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,1),
                sell = c(20, 21, 19, 18, 23,24, 36, 35, 46, 50,44),
                demand=c(28, 16, 43,NaN,NaN,30, 35, 35, 72,NaN, 60)
                 )

df$`demand-sell` <- df$demand - df$sell

df
```

Expected Output_function:
[image: Output_function]

```html
**For week = 4**<br/>
In which I would like to fill NaN values of demand for week = 4 with sum of remaining demand (demand - sell) of week = 1,2,3 of the same seller (name)<br/><br/>

**Note:**<br/>

If week=4 demand is not NaN then add week=4 demand in (demand - sell) of week = 1,2,3<br/>

{<b>ex</b> in case of name = jack }<br/><br/>

**For week = 5:**

<br/>In which I would like to fill NaN values of demand for week = 5 with sum of remaining demand (demand - sell) of week = 1,2,3,4 of the same seller (name)


<br/>**Note:**


<br/>If week=5 demand is not NaN then add week=5 demand in (demand - sell) of week = 1,2,3,4<br/>
```

Expected Output (sample data)

[image: Expected_output_sample]

Comment: Please see my update. Now it is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update with the correct answer:**

The issue was the lack of `is.nan(demand)`statement:

Here is the correct answer:

```
    df %>% 
        mutate(`demand-sell` = demand - sell) %>%
        group_by(name) %>% 
        mutate(demand=case_when(week == 4 & is.nan(demand) ~ sum(`demand-sell`[1:3]),
                                week == 4 & !is.nan(demand) ~ demand + sum(`demand-sell`[1:3]),
                                TRUE ~ demand)) %>% 
        mutate(`demand-sell`= case_when(week == 4 ~ demand-sell,
                                        TRUE ~ `demand-sell`)) %>% 
        mutate(demand = case_when(week == 5 ~ `demand-sell`[4],
                                  TRUE ~ demand)) %>% 
        mutate(`demand-sell`= case_when(week == 5 ~ demand-sell,
                                        TRUE ~ `demand-sell`))
```

**Correct output:**

```
   name   week  sell demand `demand-sell`
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 Tom       1    20     28             8
 2 Tom       2    21     16            -5
 3 Tom       3    19     43            24
 4 Tom       4    18     27             9
 5 Tom       5    23      9           -14
 6 jack      1    24     30             6
 7 jack      2    36     35            -1
 8 jack      3    35     35             0
 9 jack      4    46     77            31
10 jack      5    50     31           -19
11 Malik     1    44     60            16
```

**First answer:**
Here is a solution: At least for `Tom` it is correct. I don't know if your excepted output for `jack` is correct.
If the logic for all `name` is the same it should look like this:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(`demand-sell` = demand - sell) %>%
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(demand=case_when(week == 4 ~ sum(`demand-sell`[1:3]),
                            TRUE ~ demand)) %>% 
    mutate(`demand-sell`= case_when(week == 4 ~ demand-sell,
                                    TRUE ~ `demand-sell`)) %>% 
    mutate(demand = case_when(week == 5 ~ `demand-sell`[4],
           TRUE ~ demand)) %>% 
    mutate(`demand-sell`= case_when(week == 5 ~ demand-sell,
                                    TRUE ~ `demand-sell`))
```

Output:

```
   name   week  sell demand `demand-sell`
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 Tom       1    20     28             8
 2 Tom       2    21     16            -5
 3 Tom       3    19     43            24
 4 Tom       4    18     27             9
 5 Tom       5    23      9           -14
 6 jack      1    24     30             6
 7 jack      2    36     35            -1
 8 jack      3    35     35             0
 9 jack      4    46      5           -41
10 jack      5    50    -41           -91
11 Malik     1    44     60            16
```